# LWP::UserAgent - Print HTML content

Tags: perl, user-agent, lwp

I am trying to get the HTML content using the following code, but unable to do so. Can somebody please help me..

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $response = $ua->request("http://google.co.uk");

print $response->as_string;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, read the error you get when executing this:

```
You need a request object, not 'http://google.co.uk' at ... line 3
```

Then, read the documentation how to use LWP::UserAgent. Hint: what you want is probably `get` and not `request`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $response = $ua->get("http://google.co.uk");

print $response->content;
```